# what's the below Unix shell mean?

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
# copydir.sh

#  Copy (verbose) all files in current directory ($PWD)
#+ to directory specified on command-line.

E_NOARGS=85

if [ -z "$1" ]   # Exit if no argument given.
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` directory-to-copy-to"
  exit $E_NOARGS
fi  

ls . | xargs -i -t cp ./{} $1

exit 0
```

"./{} "  what is this mean? and what is this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./{}` is a reference to the current file that `xargs` receives as parameter, in particular `./` means "this folder" and `{}` is the filename itself.

I was expecting it to have the `-n1` flag also, to specify that files should be passed one at a time.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I got it.

Comment: Consider upvoting / accepting the answer if it solves your problem